# Unrecognized expression using Thickbox with Divi WP Theme

Tags: jquery

I have a plugin that uses thickbox on the frontend. The HTML button for the thickbox modal is:

```
<a href="#TB_inline?width=640&height=600&inlineId=modal-window-id" class="thickbox">My Link
</a>
```

A user is using the Divi theme. It registers an event that gets triggered when the above link is clicked:

```
$('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function () {
    ....

    var target = $(this.hash);

    ....
});
```

The above line of code generates the following error:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression #TB_inline?width=640&height=600&inlineId=modal-window-id jquery.js:2:12733
```

Can anyone see why this error is getting thrown?

Comment: Doing it that way its looking for an `id="#TB_inline?width=640&he..."` instead try `$('[href="'+this.hash+'"]);`

Comment: Sorry, whats the target ment to be the link, which you already got in the selector :/

Comment: @rwkiii, what do you trying to achieve? waht you expect to be the "target"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply because

```
#TB_inline?width=640&height=600&inlineId=modal-window-id
$('#TB_inline?width=640&height=600&inlineId=modal-window-id')
```

Is not a valid jQuery selector.

Comment: We don't need the Divi script so I added `:not([href*="#TB_inline"])` to the Divi selector. @2oppin is right as to why this was happening. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

your selector is not valid. # is a special char and needs to be escaped like `a[href*=\\#]:not([href=\\#])`

see https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/